# ES Index name and Stormcrawler

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I've been working with Stormcrawler for a few days now and am getting comfortable with it. I've been following the [guide](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch) for indexing with ES.

How can I change the name of the ES Index that Stormcrawler sends the data to?

I've been playing with the ES_IndexInit.sh script but it seems no matter what I do, it sends the crawl data to the ***index*** index. Its fine to get started and do some testing but I want to create my own indices and mappings now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set via the config, see [es-conf example](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml#L6) 'es.indexer.index.name'

Comment: ok now I feel lazy. I've looked at the file and just didn't see it. Need fresh eyes, thanks.